# Running a script by checking a checkbox on two different sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having odd behavior on my code.

I need the script to trigger when I'm using an Ipad or a mobile phone.
I was able to have it work on one sheet "Existing client". Now I'm trying to have a second sheet "new client" that also has the same behavior but triggers others functions.
The thing is it looks like when I switch between sheets, the checkbox needs to be checked multiple times and does not trigger all the time. My solution would be to simply make another spreadsheet for the second sheet "new client" but I would still like to understand what is wrong with what I did?
Here is the code:
So I reduce the code to a minimum, meaning if i check the box, I have the time stamp in a cell. If I have two sheets, it is not working.
Thanks for your help,
j.

```
function onEditTriggerClientExistant() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Client existant");
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  if (range.isChecked()) {
    if (range.getA1Notation() == "B4") {
    sheet.getRange('C4').setValue(new Date());
    range.uncheck();
    
    } else  {
    range.uncheck()
  }
}
}

function onEditTriggerNouveauClient() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Nouveau Client");
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  if (range.isChecked()) {
    if (range.getA1Notation() == "A4") {
    sheet.getRange('B4').setValue(new Date());
    range.uncheck();
    
    } else  {
    range.uncheck()
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, what makes you think the script is not getting triggered? Have you checked the execution logs? Also, consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's not clear what's going on here.

Comment: Hi, the spreadsheet you provided is not accessible. Consider making it publicly accessible (remove all sensitive information).

Comment: Oups sorry. here a better version https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pZxsgPlN48ul3KlX6jyy3EYb8s1nbxWfp-vW11wW3s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, you provided a script with more than 400 lines, using several different services, in any of which an error could be happening, as well as some undefined variables. This is hardly a minimal reproducible example. Have you looked at the `Executions` tab, to check whether the script is not getting triggered at all, or whether it is getting triggered but throwing an error? Also, I assume you have installed 2 triggers, one for `onEditTriggerNouveauClient` and one for `onEditTriggerClientExistant`?

Comment: Hi, yes I did install them both of them. The thing is I need to check the box a second time to make it trigger. If I have only one sheet and one trigger, I do not have this problem.

Comment: This is the message I get in the Executions : **16 juin 2022, 11:41:23 Erreur Exception: Échec de la requête pour https://docs.google.com. Code renvoyé : 429. Réponse tronquée du serveur : <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="fr"><head><meta name="description" content="Traitement de texte, présentations et feuilles de calcul en ligne"><meta nam... (Utilisez l'option muteHttpExceptions pour examiner la réponse entière.)
    at [unknown function](Code:341:28)**

Comment: code 429 looks like I'm sending too many requests. Could it come from the emails I'm sending every time I test the code? I'll pause this part of the code and see if it is working better. The user should trigger the code twice a day so it should not be a concern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245662/discussion-between-julien-and-iamblichus).

Answer (score 0):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
function onEdit(e) {
  let oldValue = e.oldValue;
  let newValue = e.value;
  var r = e.range.getRow()
  var c = e.range.getColumn()
  var active_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var sheetName = active_sheet.getName();
  if(sheetName=="sheet1" && r==4 && c==2){

  }
  else if(sheetName=="sheet2" && r==4 && c==1){

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arslan, thanks for this code but I can use onEdit(e) because of use on a mobile devices and on a specific checkbox.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).